# In mvc after register an new user dont want to sign in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I have created mvc web app.
I have used membership provider for registration.

But, when I registered a new user, it automatically gets logged in,
I don't want this rather I want to check, if `isapproved` property is false, then it should have to move on any other page say on

```
//redirect to Welcome page
return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
```

Also want to check users role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Darin gave you the answer about bypassing the immediate log in after registration. For your other question, you probably have something like below on your registration action method:

```
Membership.CreateUser(
    model.UserName, 
    model.Password, 
    model.Email, 
    null, 
    null, 
    true, 
    null, 
    out createStatus
);
```

This is [one of the overload methods of CreateUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82xx2e62.aspx) of [Membership class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx).

Change it with this in order to set the `IsApproved` to `false`.

```
Membership.CreateUser(
    model.UserName, 
    model.Password, 
    model.Email, 
    null, 
    null, 
    false, 
    null, 
    out createStatus
);
```

Then, on the log in part, when you check the validity of the user with below code, you do not need to check if the user is approved or not. It does that for you:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply remove the following call from the `Register` action:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

This is what emits the authentication cookie and on the subsequent request (after the redirect) and the user is considered authenticated. Without emitting the authentication cookie, the user will not be signed in.

Comment: thanks you how can i deal with isapproved = true ?? any link ??
i need to make it through admin please help